# discord.py - use long query and flags without double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I enter a longer text (e.g. a song) without double quotes?

My command looks like this:

```py
@commands.command(brief="play [track] <options>")
async def play(self, ctx, query: str, *, options: Options) -> None:
```

I can only use it like this: **play "Sweet Dreams" --now** instead of **play Sweet Dreams --now**.

---

If I place * infront of query, like this:

```py
@commands.command(brief="play [track] <options>")
async def play(self, ctx, *, query: str, options: Options) -> None:
```

I get this error:
`Command raised an exception: TypeError: play() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'options'`

---

My flag looks like this:

```py
class Options(commands.FlagConverter, delimiter=" ", prefix="--"):
    next: bool = False
    now: bool = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter after `*` collects everything that wasn't already collected by the command. Your code errors out because discord.py expects only zero or one keyword-only argument: it puts everything in it, so there is nothing left for the second one you define.

Instead, you can get the whole content into the one keyword-only argument and then manually parse any options from there.

You need a way to differentiate what is part of the text and where the options begin. Let's say you expect the user to put the options on their own line, such that the last newline will mark the start of the options.

```py
@commands.command(brief="play [track] <options>")
async def play(self, ctx, *, content: str) -> None:
    query, _, options = content.rpartition("\n")

    if (options := options.strip()).startswith("--"):
        # There are actually options here
        options = Options.convert(options)
    else:
        # This line is actually the last line of the query and no option was given
        query += f"\n{options}"

    ...
```

In case you're not familiar with `(options := options.strip())`, that's the walrus operator. It's equivalent to `options = options.strip()` but saves a little code. If you're using Python <3.8 you can put the latter on the line before the `if`.

Comment: thats the only way to do it?

Comment: If you want to avoid quotes, yes, because each parameter the command has corresponds to one space-separated word given when you call the command. The only exceptions are if you quote something, and it's then treated as a whole as a single argument, or the keyword-only parameter, which takes everything left without splitting it in any way (because it wouldn't know what rule to follow to do so). Discord.py also makes it clear in the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments.

Comment: You could find a different way to parse what you need from `content` (for example using something different than `\n`) but there is no way around either using quotes or manually parsing `content`, short of reimplementing the command parsing itself to use it instead of discordpy's.